# Can SOAPUI run LoadTest TestSteps sequentially

Tags: soapui, loadui

I have a LoadTest in SoapUI with a TestSuite of 3 TestSteps, Step1, Step2 and Step3. I want to run the TestSuite from 10 concurrent threads where each threads runs the TestSuite 10 times.
When I set this up in SoapUI the TestSuite isn't run as I thought it would. Instead of running Step1 then Step2 and then Step3 and repeat this 10 times, it seems as SoapUI first runs Step1 10 times, then Step2 10 times, and then last Step3 10 times.

Anyone who knows how to force SoapUI to run the TestSuite 10 times instead?

And please don't say "Run loadUI" because I don't want to :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can do this if you add the '`DataSource`' and '`DataSourceLoop`' and delay. The set the test data from data source and in DataSourceLoop (set datasourcestep as  and Target as delay(set the delay as minimal)), then it will work.

I have set for fixed load where 25 users come and executed one step after the other and next set come, to test how it work. After setting in Loadui select 'RunOnce' you will see one step after other.

Hope this might help you.